# verticalHorizontal scroll Listview for android TV app

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, smooth-scrolling, google-tv, android-tv

I had a requirement of implementing a Header List view with horizontal scroll items as rows (similar to UI shown by using Browse fragment of leanback library) for android TV app . I browsed on net and used verticalHorizontalscroll view using Two way View example and added a header text.As the app is for android TV , both Horizontal and Vertical scrolling should happen on keys Navigation and should show a selector to the focused item.

The vertical Scrolling and Horizontal scrolling is not happening properly.

**VericalScrolling**:
while scrolling up and down using Keys the entire row is not scrolling it is showing only half of the row on screen. When i set setItemsCanFocus is true it taking two key presses to scroll entire row. One for scrolling row and one for scrolling the header text.

**HorizontalScrolling:** Horizontal scrolling is not happening until we set setItemsCanFocus is true only after this it is showing selector on focused item . It is taking multiple Right key presses to scroll one item to right.

Please anyone tell me how can i get smooth scrolling both horizontal and vertical along with selector for TV. Is there any other way i can implement this.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain more with posting screen shot.

Comment: had a similar problem in vertical scrolling
Solved it just by replacing listview with gridview with single column
But I didn't get your problem in horizontal scrolling i.e teo way listview